# Chrome Extension: Local Storage, how to export

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a chrome extension that saves a bunch of data to chrome.storage.local. I'm trying to find easy ways to export this data and package it into a file. I'm not constrained on what type of file it is (JSON, CSV, whatever), I just need to be able to export the contents into a standalone (and send-able) file. The extension is only run locally and the user would have access to all local files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, you need to get all data.
Then serialize the result.
Finally, offer it as a download to the user.

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) { // null implies all items
    // Convert object to a string.
    var result = JSON.stringify(items);

    // Save as file
    var url = 'data:application/json;base64,' + btoa(result);
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: url,
        filename: 'filename_of_exported_file.json'
    });
});
```

To use the [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) method, you need to declare the `"downloads"` permission in addition to the `storage` permission in the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies I'm a bit delayed in verifying. As soon as I'm able, and assuming this is the best route, I'll mark correct. Thank you!

Comment: I am getting chrome is not define  what i should import in my service . file ?

Comment: How to restore this JSON file to local storage? Thank

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/AzO_taH2b7U

It shows exporting chrome local storage to JSON.

Hope it helps

Comment: That is not [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), but `localStorage`.

Comment: @unit998x, thanks for the response. I've seen this post before and it works fine to display the contents in JSON format. But this doesn't prompt the user to download the output. I've heard someone recommend to then using HTML5's file handling, but it would be easier if there is a chrome API to handle this (as it is already stored in chrome.storage). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blob, and simulate the download using an anchor tag.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(data) {
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  // Create a Blob containing the JSON data
  var blob = new Blob([jsonData], { type: 'application/json' });

  // Create a download link and trigger a click event to download the file
  var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadLink.download = 'extension_data.json';
  downloadLink.click();
});
```